# Jade: how to pass a Jade block as a string to a Mixin

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I've been given a Jade template where in a particular moment there's a call to a mixin. We pass some parameters to that mixin, one of them is a quite long HTML string that the mixin is in charge to print via `!=`

It goes like:

```
+createHTML({firstSection:'<div>some text and more HTML tags nested in here</div>'})
```

and printed on screen with:

```
mixin createHTML(obj)
    section
        !=obj.firstSection
```

Though this is currently working, **problem is**: HTML string passed as a parameter is quite long in reality, with many nested tags, text, etc, and for legible reasons I'd like to construct the HTML using Jade syntax, convert it into a string and pass it to the mixin. Is that even possible? Something like:

```
block myHTML
    div
        p sometext in #[strong bold] here
        p more text

- var stringHTML = toString(myHTML)

 +createHTML({firstSection:stringHTML})
```

Comment: Why don't you put the jade code to another file and simply includes it with **include blah.jade**?

Answer (score 0):

Jade mixins support **one** block parameter. You can pass a block of jade to a mixin like so:

**mixin definition:**

```
mixin profile(name)
  article.profile
    h1 #{name}
    block
```

**mixin call:**

```
+profile('Mr Tickle')
  p Lorem ipsum
  ul
    li some stuff
    li more stuff
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Maybe I didn't express myself well. Problem is that mixin has to receive an Object with more properties. ie:

 `+createHTML({firstSection:stringHTML,someotherprop:'Hello World',otherprop:'Today's prices are lower'})` that's the reason why the HTML has to be passed in the Object Literal style so that when received will be painted like:

`mixin createHTML(obj)

    !=obj.firstSection

    !=obj.someOtherProp`

Comment: In which case you may be out of luck. I recall trying to store the result of a jade expression as a variable (in jade) a while ago and not finding a solution. Sorry!